# JAVA objected 2D array ,Can't set the element in array nor call the function in it

Tags: java, object, multidimensional-array, minesweeper

i'm trying to create an minesweeper game using this [Class Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnjEm.jpg)
I'm stuck here for 2 hours and can't find any solution to it,while i'm trying to call the function in the GridData class,the NullPointerException always heppen,Also i can't change the element in an array, Anyone has a suggestion ?

```
public GridData[][] board ;
```

public BomberGame(int boardSize,int bombNo){

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
if(boardSize < 3)
    board = new GridData[3][3] ;
else
    board = new GridData[boardSize][boardSize];


 for (i = 0; i < boardSize; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < boardSize; j++)
        {
            //board[i][j]BomberGame = 0 ;// here is the problem i can't mess with any element in array
            board[i][j].setIsOpen(true); // after doing NullPointerException occur
            board[i][j].gridIsOpen();
            System.out.print(board[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
```

}

Output

```
null null null
null null null
null null null
```

[Class Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue1Fy.jpg)

Comment: When you create a array in Java all the values are ``null``. You have to create the instances first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `new GridData[3][3];` will just get you the `null` array. You'll have to initialize each element in it by doing:

```
for (i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < boardSize; j++) {
        board[i][j] = new GridData();
    }
}
```

Once you initialize the array, you can proceed with rest of the code.

Here is the code snippet:

```
for (i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < boardSize; j++) {
        board[i][j] = new GridData();
        board[i][j].setIsOpen(true); 
        board[i][j].gridIsOpen();
        System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
board = new GridData[3][3];
```

Here, you only create the array. Now, each element in the array also needs to be allocated. Like:

```
board[i][j] = new GridData();
```